# When to open hibernate connection and hibernate session?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-session

I have a question related to Hibernate Connection, Session and SessionFactory. The queries are as below:

1) Is it a good practice to open up a connection on every request and close it after that?

2) There is a single sessionfactory which opens up the sessions for each request, What is the correlation of it with Connection? I know that on connection the sessionfactory opens sessions for different requests, When should open up and close a connection and when should we just open up a session and close it? Is it like, we should open a new connection on every login and close that connection on logout or hibernate does it itself?

Thanks in advance for your kind review

Regards
Rahul

Comment: Hibernate doesn't have connections. JDBC has connections. If you use Hibernate, Hibernate will open and close connections for you. Please show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to open up a connection on every request and
>   close it after that?

No this is not good practice.see [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#connection%28%29) with Hibernate use connection pooling

> There is a single sessionfactory which opens up the sessions for each request, What is the correlation of it with Connection?

Hibernate uses the connection pool when we get the `session` from `SessoinFactory` from one of the connections are allocated to session

> When should open up and close a connection

With hibernate you don't worry about the JDBC `Connection` as long as you are thinking about the performance

> when should we just open up a session and close it

For all the CRUD operations

> Is it like, we should open a new connection on every login and close that connection on logout or hibernate does it itself?

No User login and JDBC `Connection` has no relation